# Conceptnet5 python setup mac OS

Tags: python

I am trying to install conceptnet locally on a mac.

I took The high-bandwidth, low-computation way https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Running-your-own-copy and did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5
pyvenv-3.4 conceptnet-env
source conceptnet-env/bin/activate
cd conceptnet5
python setup.py develop
make download_db
```

Then at the last step i am getting the following error :

command

```
ln -s `readlink -f data` ~/.conceptnet5
```

output

```
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
```

So i did ignored this step, because i had seen a google discussion which proposed another method (as the link command was not working for me)

So from this discussion https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/issues/33 I tried the following :

```
CONCEPTNET_DATA=~/conceptnet5/data/
export CONCEPTNET_DATA
```

But this didnt work, cause when doing the following :

```
from conceptnet5.query import lookup
lookup('/c/en/examples')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/arj/Desktop/app/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/query.py", line 75, in lookup
    self.load_index()
  File "/Users/arj/Desktop/app/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/query.py", line 58, in load_index
    self._db_filename, self._edge_dir, self.nshards
  File "/Users/arj/Desktop/app/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/formats/sql.py", line 211, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/Users/arj/Desktop/app/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/formats/sql.py", line 216, in _connect
    self.dbs[i] = sqlite3.connect(filename)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

What should be the OS equivalent of the ln command?

Or what else can i do for conceptnet to locate the database file ?